# Neo4j - Cypher node and relationship relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = {decisionGroupId} 
MATCH (filterCharacteristic1:Characteristic) 
WHERE filterCharacteristic1.id = 1 
WITH dg, filterCharacteristic1 
CALL apoc.index.between(childD,'HAS_VALUE_ON',filterCharacteristic1,'(value:(10))') YIELD rel 
WITH DISTINCT rel, childD, dg 
MATCH (childD)-(rel)  // here I need to go further only with 'childD' nodes that have relationship with 'rel'(match `apoc.index.between` predicate)
```

As you may see from the query above  - at the end I'm trying to filter `childD` nodes that have the relationship with `rel` but I don't know how to describe it in Cypher. Something like `(childD)-(rel)`  or `(childD)-[rel]` doesn't work and leads to the error.  Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for a match pattern and compare the relationship:

```
...
WITH DISTINCT rel, childD, dg 
MATCH (childD)-[tmp]-() WHERE tmp = rel
RETURN rel, child, dg
```

Or you can compare directly:

```
...
WITH DISTINCT rel, childD, dg, startNode(rel) AS sRel, endNode(rel) AS eRel 
WHERE (childD)--(sRel) OR (childD)--(eRel)
RETURN rel, child, dg
```